# Prevent "Press ENTER or type command to continue" prompt after external command executes

Tags: external-command, grep

I am using `:grep` to search for occurences of a string within a set of files:

```
:grep rainbow *.txt
```

This result is then shown in the terminal:

```
doc1.txt:2:saw a rainbow today
doc2.txt:17:it was not a black rainbow
doc3.txt:7:most of those rainbow unicorns
(1 of 3): saw a rainbow today
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

To get back to Vim, I need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I don't want to have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Is there a way to prevent the prompt?

I know I can do this to prevent the prompt:

```
:silent :grep rainbow *.txt
:redraw!
```

But that's a lot of extra letters to have to type.

Answer (score 9):

If what you're looking for is a way to automate the sequence of commands (`:silent grep` and `redraw!`), then consider creating a new [user-defined command](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#user-commands) for that operation.

(In fact, Vim documentation essentially [recommends it for this particular use case](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#grep) with their `NewGrep` example.)

My recommendation would be:

```
command! -nargs=+ -complete=file Grep
    \ execute 'silent grep! <args>' | redraw! | cfirst
```

This would:

- Define `:Grep` as the new command.
- Sets up command completion to search for files, which matches the type of completion available for `:grep`.
- Use `:silent` and `:redraw!` as expected.
- Use `:grep!` and jump to the first target explicitly with `cfirst`. This is done so you'll see the line `(1 of 3): saw a rainbow today` after jumping to the first result.

If you like to work with the quickfix window most of the time, consider using `copen` instead of `cfirst` to open that window directly.

Comment: Also consider `cwindow` instead of `copen`. `cwindow` does not open the quickfix window when nothing was found.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to do a redraw...per [`:h :!cmd`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#:!cmd)...

> This requires a hit-enter prompt, so that you can read any messages. To avoid this use `:silent !{cmd}`. The screen is not redrawn then....

But if you're simply looking to reduce the number of keys to press perhaps I can interest you in an 89% reduction of the second command. A single key combo...

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

> ...thus you have to use `CTRL-L` or `:redraw!` if the command did display something.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `:vimgrep`. Do `:h vimgrep` or watch the screencast from Drew Neil at http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-multiple-files-with-vimgrep/. You can even use vim's regexes when searching.
It won't open the quickfix window, but will take you to the first occurence of the search term.